# SQL Trigger for Overlapping Dates

Tags: mysql, triggers

How can I create a trigger using the below code to stop overlapping dates in my booking table? Currently it's not working and i'm getting the following error.

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF EXISTS

(SELECT *
FROM booking_requests
WHERE DateOfArrival <= NEW.' at line 3

```
CREATE TRIGGER date_overlap
BEFORE INSERT ON hotel_booking 
IF EXISTS
(
SELECT *
FROM booking_requests
WHERE DateOfArrival <= NEW.DateOfDeparture
AND DateOfDeparture >= NEW.DateOfArrival
AND (RoomNumber != NEW.RoomNumber)
)
THEN
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'overlapping date entries are not supported.';
END IF;
```

Comment: Looks like MySQL, right?

Comment: this will kill your performance!

Comment: Dbschema, sample data, expected result. Give us something to work with. Right now this is very poor written question.  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
IF EXISTS (
... # this part looks about right, except for the last line, which
    # you only need in the update trigger and should simply say:
  AND (id != NEW.id)
) THEN
  SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
  SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'overlapping date entries are not supported.';
END IF;
```

Valid for MySQL Server 5.5 and later.

This needs to be in both a `BEFORE INSERT` and a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger.

Multi-column indexes on both (date_start,date_end) and (date_end,date_start) will allow the optimizer the best chance of identifying conflicting rows quickly, since it can search via range on either column and scan the values in other from the index directly, using it as a covering index.